# Android: Is it Possible to Add Custom Attributes to Extended Views?

Tags: android, xml, schema, adt

I know I can extend an Android view and have seen the Notepad example of doing this.  I was wondering if it is possible in addition to add new custom attributes for the view that would parse properly in the XML declarations of the custom view.  I'm a bit of a novice at XML technology.

I read [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) that I can somehow add custom attributes in the custom view's constructor, but there is no detail given and no example shown.

Ideally I would also like to be able to extend the ADT visual layout previewer/editor to support the custom views (rendering them with my custom code and having the custom properties show up in the context menu, etc.)

I would love to be able to do this but am not sure it's feasible or even possible.  I read that XML schema may or may not be extensible:  ["extend" an xml schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585959/extend-an-xml-schema)

If this scenario isn't directly supported, does someone know where to find the Android schema so I might be able to modify it directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [the answer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/package-summary.html) myself.  The ApiDemos LabelView application has an example of this.  I haven't yet verified whether or not the visual editor shows the custom behavior though.

Comment: That link is dead :-( I think this is the updated link for the ApiDemos LabelView application - http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/LabelView.html

Comment: @BenClayton Thanks, I updated my hyperlink, which points to the widget documentation.

Answer (score 0):

the panel widget in this project has its on xmlns its a pretty solid example not sure about your ADT question either
http://code.google.com/p/android-misc-widgets/